# When I sort a dataFrame and then write it to a csv file, the values get converted to float, How to avoid this?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a df:

```
 Id     Reputation
  1       50
  3       20
  2       10
```

If I sort by reputation I have

```
 Id     Reputation
  2       10
  3       20
  1       50
```

After executing
     df.to_csv("output.csv", index = False)

In my CSV file :

```
 Id,Reputation
 2,10.0
 3,20.0
 1,50.0
```

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt it that sorting changed dtype.  You can check (before sorting):

```
print df.dtypes
```

I guess `Reputation` was float. 
Anyway, you can always change dtypes before to_csv:

```
df['Reputation'] = df['Reputation'].astype(int)
```